# How to download zip file from internet using JAVA and saving it in a specific folder?

Tags: java, url, exception

**This is my code:**

```
public static void downloadZipFile() {
    String saveTo = "C:\\Users\\aria\\Downloads\\Temp";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.bcfi.be/download/files/R1112B2_BcfiHtm.zip");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(saveTo + "BcfiHtm.zip");
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(b)) >= 0) {
            out.write(b, 0, count);
        }
        out.flush(); out.close(); in.close();                   

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**When i compile it i get following error but if i use url directly in browsers evrything is ok.

How can i fix it? or is there any other way to download zip file?**

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.bcfi.be
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
at be.azvub.ext.prismaFlex.Exterahelp.download.DownloadFile.downloadZipFile(DownloadFile.java:72)
at be.azvub.ext.prismaFlex.Exterahelp.download.DownloadFile.main(DownloadFile.java:37)
```

Comment: It's not a Java problem, seems like you have a problem with the network lookup. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Can you download using a browser? I could but I hope the zip file doesn't contain sensitive data.

Comment: In my case I got the Connection Time out. Below solution helped me tooo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from the Java Docs:

> Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be
>   determined.

Make sure your program is not blocked by the **Firewall** or a **proxy**.

**UPDATE:**

To configure you proxy, do as Peter Liljenberg suggested:

> You could pass the proxy information to the openConnection call in
>   your code like this:
>
> Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new
>   InetSocketAddress("pro",9999)); URLConnection conn =
>   url.openConnection(proxy);

Comment: I"m behind proxy server, how can i fix it?proxy hostneam is "pro" and port is "9999"

Comment: @itro You have to allow your program through the proxy (I actually have no experience how to do it)

Comment: Nice one Adel. You are a Life Saver!

Answer (score 6):

Since you're behind a proxy you can try some different approaches:

1) Add the proxy information to the JVM when starting:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber 
-Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName -Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword javaClassToRun
```

In your case it would probably be:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=pro -Dhttp.proxyPort=9999  javaClassToRun
```

2) You could pass the proxy information to the openConnection call in your code like this:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("pro",9999));
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
```